# Efficiently returning multiple values in C

Tags: c, inlining, multiple-return-values

When a C function has to return multiple values, there's a few ways to go about that.

Right now I'm interested in the relative efficiency of two of those methods:
a) bundle the values in a struct foo.  Populate a local foo, and return that.
b) pass pointers to be populated.

(I'm working on some legacy code that has a mix of the two.)

For the purposes of this post:

- All returned values are primitives. Int's, pointer values, etc. So sizeof(foo) is very small.
- Making struct foo opaque isn't a concern.
- The functions in question have at most 12 parameters, including any ptr-to-return-value parameters.
- Assume a somewhat modern compiler, e.g. gcc 11 or later.

Obviously inlining would make the question moot.
Can the different methods affect the compiler's ability to inline?
If not inlined, will there be a performance difference between the two methods?

Can placement of a pointer-to-return-val parameters in the function arguments have an effect? Either on the compiler's ability to inline, or on non-inlined performance?

Edited (a) for clarity.

Comment: I think the only way for you to find out is to experiment and see. I'm absolutely convinced that the ability to inline or not for different scenarios vary among compilers and platforms.

Comment: I'd be inclined to pass a pointer to a struct, have the function fill it out and return true/false depending on whether it was completely successful. And then I'd let the compiler worry about optimization.

Comment: "Right now I'm interested in the relative efficiency of two of those methods:" belongs to [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80094/94903).

Comment: @RM: These functions are called a LOT, often billions of times with a few minutes. We've used perf to locate hot-spots and some of these functions are definitely involved.

Comment: In option `b)` only 8-bytes are passed and no copying takes place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specific.

On [Linux / x86-64](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf), a `struct` with exactly two words (e.g. two pointers or two `intptr_t` or two `long`-s) is returned in two registers. This is a lot faster than e.g. `malloc`-ing it, and might be faster than writing a two words `struct` allocated on the call stack by the caller (then it is likely to be in some fast [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache); remember that on recent processors a cache miss may take hundreds of nanoseconds, or the time needed for a hundred of register to register integer addition machine instructions)

But inlining a function is not always faster. You could also use partial evaluation techniques or C++ code generation.

With a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, consider also compiling all C or C++ files *and linking* with link-time optimization (e.g. `-flto -O2`)

Comment: The project has -O2. But -flto breaks it (currently under investigation as to why.)

Comment: This would be a local struct, populated and then returned. No malloc.  I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. The malloc bits aren't relevant, but it brought up registers. Which is probably the only optimization that would have a real effect in the cases I'm looking at.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* the question is: which is faster (assuming no inlining):

```
void fn(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
  *a = ...;
  *b = ...;
  ... etc.
}
```

vs.

```
void fn(struct foo *f) {
  f->a = ...;
  f->b = ...;
  ... etc.
}
```

*In isolation*, the `struct` variant will be faster, because it will not have to load the individual pointers from memory (on `x86` you can only pass a few pointers in registers, and the rest will be spilled into stack).

However, the caller context also matters. If the caller looks like this:

```
int a; double d1; int b; double d2; int c; ...
struct foo f;
fn(&f);
a = f->a;
b = f->b;
... etc.
```

then the savings will be largely negated by the "unpack `foo`" code.

But if the caller looks like this:

```
struct foo f;
fn(&f);
if (f->a != 0) ...
int x = f->a + f->b;
... etc.
```

then the "unpack" code will not be present.

Comment: I may be wrong, but it sounds more like the OP is talking about returning the struct _by value_ from the function.

Comment: @Chris The compiler will likely convert "return by value" into the "allocate struct on stack and pass a pointer to it" anyway (NRVO).

Comment: Not necessarily.  According to some ABIs, small enough structs are returned by value in (possibly multiple) registers.

Comment: @Chris : correct.  Similar to returning an std::pair<>

Comment: @John and ER : yes, these structs would tend to be very small - generally one pointer and one int.